# Comparison between datetime and datetime64[ns] in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime64

I'm writing a program that checks an excel file and if today's date is in the excel file's date column, I parse it

I'm using:

```
cur_date = datetime.today()
```

for today's date. I'm checking if today is in the column with:

```
bool_val = cur_date in df['date'] #evaluates to false
```

I do know for a fact that today's date is in the file in question. The dtype of the series is datetime64[ns]

Also, I am only checking the date itself and not the timestamp afterwards, if that matters. I'm doing this to make the timestamp 00:00:00:

```
cur_date = datetime.strptime(cur_date.strftime('%Y_%m_%d'), '%Y_%m_%d')
```

And the type of that object after printing is datetime as well

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use

```
pd.Timestamp('today')
```

or

```
pd.to_datetime('today')
```

But both of those give the date and time for `'now'`.

---

Try this instead:

```
pd.Timestamp('today').floor('D')
```

or

```
pd.to_datetime('today').floor('D')
```

---

You could have also passed the `datetime` object to `pandas.to_datetime` but I like the other option more.

```
pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime.today()).floor('D')
```

---

Pandas also has a `Timedelta` object

```
pd.Timestamp('now').floor('D') + pd.Timedelta(-3, unit='D')
```

Or you can use the `offsets` module

```
pd.Timestamp('now').floor('D') + pd.offsets.Day(-3)
```

---

To check for membership, try one of these

```
cur_date in df['date'].tolist()
```

Or

```
df['date'].eq(cur_date).any()
```

Comment: What if I was checking for 3 days before the current date? I did today = today - timedelta(3) when it was a datetime object

Comment: `pd.Timestamp('today').floor('D') - pd.offsets.Day(3)`

Comment: Is there a resource on what exactly `to_datetime` will accept? Does it just boil down to a case of trial-and-error/read the source? The docs just seem to say "arg : integer, float, string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, Series" which is... kinda extensive.

Comment: That about sums it up.  By resource, do you mean a doc that demonstrates all of the above?

Comment: @piRSquared yeah, maybe I was hoping for too much, but my search drew nothing so I threw in a last-ditch question to see if you knew a specific resource.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not.  Would make a decent canonical or pr though.

Comment: I'm still getting false when I try to check 


    `cur_date = pd.Timestamp('today').floor('D') - 
    pd.offsets.Day(3)`

    `bool_val = cur_date in df['date'] #evaluates false`

Answer (score 119):

For anyone who also stumbled across this when comparing a dataframe date to a variable date, and this did not exactly answer your question; you can use the code below.

Instead of:

```
self.df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(self.df["date"])
```

You can import datetime and then add .dt.date to the end like:

```
self.df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(self.df["date"]).dt.date
```

Comment: I think in modern pandas you need just `.date` when `to_datetime` returns a Timestamp

Answer (score 8):

When converting datetime64 type using `pd.Timestamp()` it is important to note that you should compare it to another timestamp type. (not a datetime.date type)

---

Convert a date to numpy.datetime64

```
date = '2022-11-20 00:00:00'
date64 = np.datetime64(date)
```

Seven days ago - timestamp type

```
sevenDaysAgoTs = (pd.to_datetime('today')-timedelta(days=7))
```

convert date64 to Timestamp and see if it was in the last 7 days

```
print(pd.Timestamp(pd.to_datetime(date64)) >= sevenDaysAgoTs)
```

---

Comment: I added this answer because In future versions Timestamp and datetime.date will be considered non-comparable. 
`FutureWarning: Comparison of Timestamp with datetime.date is deprecated in order to match the standard library behavior. In a future version these will be considered non-comparable.`

Comment: Thanks, this was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on logic presented by JerryMcDonald.dev in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74552218/15395420)

If reading this after comparison between Timestamp and datetime.date has been deprecated, you can apply numpy.datetime64 to your timestamp column to make it comparable with a datetime object:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

one_day_ago_timestamp = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
past_day_data = data[pd.Series(map(np.datetime64, data.timestamp_col)) >= one_day_ago_timestamp]
```