# Not able to compare pandas datetime column to datetime fetch from DB

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to compare pandas datetime to datetime fetch from DB

pandas datetime column

```
           review_updatedAt
0 2021-01-01 00:31:14+00:00
1 2021-01-01 01:55:31+00:00
2 2021-01-01 02:43:28+00:00
3 2021-01-01 07:23:11+00:00
4 2021-01-01 05:38:10+00:00
```

And there's datetime value fetch from DB

```
result = '2021-01-01 04:51:53'
```

I want to filter the Dataframe values greater than `result`

My Efforts:

```
df['review_updatedAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['review_updatedAt'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', exact=False)

df = df[df['review_updatedAt'] > result]
```

I'm getting an Error

> TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, UTC] and datetime

I also referred the existing questions
[Comparison between datetime and datetime64[ns] in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51827134/comparison-between-datetime-and-datetime64ns-in-pandas)

Comment: the problem is you're comparing aware datetime (UTC; indicated by '+00:00') to naive datetime ('2021-01-01 04:51:53'). You can simply make `result` aware too, `result = pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01 04:51:53Z')`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works perfectly fine for me, but simply copying your code `result` is a string not a datetime for me.
Since your `TypeError` implies it is datetime for you, maybe this cleanup is sufficient:

```
result = pd.Timestamp(result,tz='UTC')
```